# a limit for integrable functions

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

"if $f$ is integrable on $[0,A]$ for every $A>0$, and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$, then 
$$
\lim_{t\to 0^+} t\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx}f(x)\: dx
$$
exists"

(I'm convinced it's true, some examples suggest that the answer is 1 for every function with these properties, but how to prove it?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each $\epsilon > 0$, break up the integral at $A$ such that 
$$1-\epsilon \leq f(x) \leq 1+ \epsilon \quad \text { for }x\geq A.$$

The first part of the integral 
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+} \int_0^A t e^{-tx} f(x) dx = 0 $$
from Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem with bounding function $|f|$ when $t<1$.

On the 2nd part 
$$(1-\epsilon) \int_A^\infty te^{-tx}  dx \leq\int_A^\infty te^{-tx} f(x) dx\leq (1+\epsilon)\int_A^\infty te^{-tx}  dx \quad\quad (1)$$
and using integration from calculus 
$$\int_A^\infty te^{-tx}  dx = -e^{-tx} \bigg|_A^\infty = e^{-tA}.$$
Take the limit as $t$ goes to $0^+$ in $(1)$, we have 
$$(1-\epsilon) \lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+} e^{-tA}  \leq \lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+}\int_A^\infty te^{-tx} f(x) dx\leq (1+\epsilon) \lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+} e^{-tA}$$

$$1-\epsilon  \leq \lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+}\int_A^\infty te^{-tx} f(x) dx\leq 1+\epsilon.$$

Comment: The use of Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem was overkill (see [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4722182/386889)).

Answer (score 1):

Let us prove that

> if $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable on $[0,A]$ for every $A>0$, and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$, then
> $$
> \lim_{t\to 0^+} t\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx}f(x)\: dx=L.
> $$

For each $\epsilon>0,$ let $A$ be such that $\forall x\ge A\quad|f(x)-L|\le\epsilon.$ Then,
$$\left|\int_A^{\infty}te^{-tx}(f(x)-L)\mathrm dx\right|\le\epsilon\int_A^{\infty}te^{-tx}\mathrm dx<\epsilon.$$
On the other hand, for any $t>0,$
$$\left|\int_0^A t e^{-tx} f(x) dx\right|\le t\int_0^A|f(x)|dx.\tag1$$
Therefore, for $t$ close enough to $0,$
$$\left|\left(t\int_0^{\infty}e^{-tx}f(x)dx\right)-L\right|=\left|\int_0^{\infty}te^{-tx}\left(f(x)-L\right)dx\right|<2\epsilon.$$

With a minor change in the proof, the same conclusion holds when replacing the hypothesis "$f$ is Lebesgue-integrable on $[0,A]$" with: "$f$ is continuous on $(0,A]$ and the Riemann improper integral $\int_0^Af(x)dx$ converges" (not necessarity absolutely): just replace the step $(1)$ with
$$\left|\int_0^Ae^{-tx} f(x) dx\right|\le\max_{c\in[0,A]}\left|\int_0^cf(x)dx\right|,$$
due to the [second mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Second_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals).

Comment: Anne Bauval, in the case of Riemann integrability, there exist integrable functions which are not absolutely integrable. So it would better to write in the hypothesis that $f$ is absolutely integrable on $[0,A]$ for every $A>0\,.$ Or do you know a way to prove the thesis even if $f$ is integrable but not absolutely integrable ?

Comment: @Angelo I was meaning Lebesgue integrable, but I added a proof in the case of (non necessarily absolutely) Riemann integrable.

Comment: Anne Bauval, why does there exist $\max\limits_{c\in[0,A]}\left|\int_0^cf(x)dx\right|$ ? Could you write a proof of the second mean value theorem ?

Comment: @Angelo 1) By continuity of this function of $c.$ 2) No.

Comment: Anne Bauval, why do not you want to write a proof of the second mean value theorem?  At least could you give me a link to a proof of it? I also need a proof of the continuity of the integral function provided that $f(x)$ is just Riemann integrable and not necessarily bounded. If it were bounded the proof would be easier (for me).

Comment: Anne Bauval, is the second mean value theorem valid for unbounded functions ? I think that the hypothesis “Riemann integrable” only refers to bounded functions. Am I wrong ? If yes, what is the reason why the product of an integrable (unbounded function) $f(x)$ and a positive monotonically descreasing function $g(x)$ is integrable too?

Comment: I did not want to write a proof of the 2nd mean value theorem because it is not the place here for that, but [here is a link to such a proof](https://books.google.fr/books?id=y6z30GiWABMC&pg=PA61). If it does not work for you, ask your prefered book, or [your friend Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=second+mean+value)
 or even only [your friend MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=second+mean+value). The answer to your last question is: by Cauchy criterion (+ 2nd mean value theorem on intervals $[a,b]\subset(0,A]$, where $f$ is bounded).

Comment: Similarly, this theorem allows, for every $a\in(0,A],$ to write $\left|\int_a^Ae^{-tx} f(x) dx\right|\le\max_{c\in(a,A]}\left|\int_a^cf(x)dx\right|,$ and then let $a\to0^+.$ As for the continuity of $c\mapsto\int_0^cf:$ it is continuous on $(0,A]$ because there, $f$ is locally bounded, and it is continuous at $0$ by definition of the improper integral.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose $f:\left[0,+\infty\right)\to\mathbb{R}$ is an absolutely integrable function on $[0,A]$ for any $A>0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\!f(x)=L.$
> Prove that $\lim\limits_{t\to 0^+}\int_{0}^{+\infty}te^{-tx}f(x)dx=L$.

**Proof :**

Let $\,\varepsilon\,$ be any positive real number ($\varepsilon>0$).

Since $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=L\,,\,$ it follows that there exists $\;N_{\varepsilon}>0\;$ such that for all $\;x\geqslant N_{\varepsilon}\;$ it results that $\;\big|f(x)-L\big|<\frac{\varepsilon}2\,.\;\color{blue}{(1)}$

Moreover,

$\displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty}\!\!\!te^{-tx}\,\mathrm dx=\left[-e^{-tx}\right]_0^{+\infty}=1\quad$ for any $\;t>0\;\;,\quad\color{blue}{(2)}$

$\displaystyle\int_{N_{\varepsilon}}^{+\infty}\!\!\!te^{-tx}\,\mathrm dx=\left[-e^{-tx}\right]_{N_{\varepsilon}}^{+\infty}=e^{-N_{\varepsilon}t}\quad$ for any $\;t>0\;.\quad\color{blue}{(3)}$

By letting $\displaystyle\;B_{\varepsilon}=\int_0^{N_{\varepsilon}}|f(x)|\,\mathrm dx\geqslant0\,,\;$ we obtain that

there exists $\;\delta_{\varepsilon}=\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2\big(B_{\varepsilon}+|L|N_{\varepsilon}+1\big)}>0\;$ such that for all $\;t\in(0,\delta_{\varepsilon})\;$ it results that

$\displaystyle\left|\int_0^{+\infty}\!\!\!\!\!te^{-tx}\!f(x)\,\mathrm dx-L\right|\overset{\color{brown}{(2)}}{=}\left|\int_0^{+\infty}\!\!\!\!\!\!te^{-tx}\!f(x)\,\mathrm dx-L\!\int_0^{+\infty}\!\!\!\!\!\!te^{-tx}\mathrm dx\right|=$

$\displaystyle=\left|\int_0^{+\infty}\!\!\!te^{-tx}\big[f(x)-L\big]\,\mathrm dx\right|\leqslant\int_0^{+\infty}\!\!\!te^{-tx}\big|f(x)-L\big|\,\mathrm dx=$

$\displaystyle=\int_0^{N_{\varepsilon}}\!\!\!te^{-tx}\big|f(x)-L\big|\,\mathrm dx+\int_{N_{\varepsilon}}^{+\infty}\!\!\!te^{-tx}\big|f(x)-L\big|\,\mathrm dx\leqslant$

$\displaystyle\leqslant\int_0^{N_{\varepsilon}}\!\!\!t\big[|f(x)|\!+\!|L|\big]\,\mathrm dx+\int_{N_{\varepsilon}}^{+\infty}\!\!\!te^{-tx}\big|f(x)\!-\!L\big|\,\mathrm dx\overset{\color{brown}{(1)}}{<}$

$\displaystyle <t\!\int_0^{N_{\varepsilon}}\!\!\!|f(x)|\,\mathrm dx+t \int_0^{N_{\varepsilon}}\!\!\!|L|\,\mathrm dx+\dfrac{\varepsilon}2\,\int_{N_{\varepsilon}}^{+\infty}\!\!\!te^{-tx}\,\mathrm dx\overset{\color{brown}{(3)}}{=}$

$\displaystyle=\big(B_{\varepsilon}+|L|N_{\varepsilon}\big)t+\dfrac{\varepsilon}2e^{-N_{\varepsilon}t}<\big(B_{\varepsilon}+|L|N_{\varepsilon}\big)\delta_{\varepsilon}+\dfrac{\varepsilon}2=$

$=\big(B_{\varepsilon}+|L|N_{\varepsilon}\big)\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2\big(B_{\varepsilon}+|L|N_{\varepsilon}+1\big)} +\dfrac{\varepsilon}2<\dfrac{\varepsilon}2+\dfrac{\varepsilon}2=\varepsilon\,.$

We have proved that

$\forall\varepsilon\!>\!0\,$ there exists $\;\delta_{\varepsilon}\!=\! \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2\big(B_{\varepsilon}+|L|N_{\varepsilon}+1\big)}>0\!\;$ such that for all $\;t\in(0,\delta_{\varepsilon})\;$ it results that $\;\displaystyle\left|\int_0^{+\infty}\!\!\!\!\!te^{-tx}\!f(x)\mathrm dx\!-\!L\right|<\varepsilon\;,$

that is, we have proved that

$\displaystyle\lim\limits_{t\to 0^{+}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}te^{-tx}f(x)dx=L\,.$

Comment: Yes Angelo, it is very clean and nice but a difficult one to think and construct.Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

The statement can be extended to the case of probability distributions  $\mu_t$  of the form $$\mu_t(dx):=t\phi(tx)\mathbb{1}_{(0,\infty)}(x)\,dx$$
where  $\phi\geq0$ is bounded above and $\int_{(0,\infty)}\phi(x)\,dx=1$.

Given $\varepsilon>0$, choose $A>0$ such that $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon/2$ for all $x\geq A$.  Then for $B>A$ and $0<t<\frac{\varepsilon}{2(\int_{(0,A]}|f|+|L|)\|\phi\|_\infty}$

\begin{align}
\Big|\int_{(0,B]}(f(x)-L )\mu_t(dx)\Big|&\leq\int_{(0,A]}|f(x)-L|\mu_t(dx)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\mu_t(A,B]\\
&\leq t\|\phi\|_\infty\int^A_0|f(x)-L|\,dx+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}<\varepsilon
\end{align}

Letting $B\rightarrow\infty$, and then $t\rightarrow0+$ we obtain
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow0+}\int^\infty_0f(x)t\phi(tx)\,dx=L$$